# How to manipulate an embedded player with time slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, windows-media-player

I am now using an embedded Windows Media Player ([tutorial](http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/embed_mediaplayer.htm)) and I can manipulate with time slider through Javascript. But then I discovered the [Jlembed](http://jasonlau.biz/home/jlembed-for-jquery) plugin for jQuery and thought it solves all my problems because of the different platforms, etc.

But after I spent a few hours in setting things up I relized that it does not have functions like  `setCurrentTime` or `getCurrentTime` and these functions are most important for my type of project.

Is there a way to achieve this functionallity with Jlembed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Windows Media Player does not support the type of interaction you're trying to achieve with it's embedded player. I did not include any javascript functions for Windows Media Player because it is not necessary. jlEmbed does not affect your ability to control the embedded player with javascript. So, if Windows Media Player supports a particular script, jlEmbed supports it also.

If there is a javascript API for WMP please point me in that direction and I will add better support for it, but I don't think it exists. However, if one does exist, jlEmbed will not prevent you from scripting as would normally be done.

I spent a great deal of time on the YouTube support, but only because I had to. Otherwise, it would have been much more difficult to control the YouTube player, which is the most popular and widely available media player on the web.

Only a small percentage of users will actually be able to use your embedded WMP presentation. The YouTube player is compatible with any browser that supports Flash. You would be better off creating a custom 'chromeless' YouTube player than using WMP for your presentation. An even better alternative would be to use Flash to make your video presentation.

Comment: Hey. I see you answered ond Jlembed comments page also (It's me overthere - Dino). I need to use WMP because of the .asf format with 2 video streams. WMP and RealPlayer opens both streams normally. About that functions on WMP, I found them somewhere on the internet , here they are: HTML: <embed id="video" type="application/x-mplayer2"></embed> JAVASCRIPT: document.getElementById('video').controls.currentPosition;document.getElementById('video').controls.currentPosition = 22.2;

Comment: Layout is terrible on comments section but I hope you can understand. Fist one return me the value of current position, and second one sets the current position to 22.2 seconds.

Comment: http://www.mioplanet.com/rsc/embed_mediaplayer.htm  here is the list of methods for WMP.

Comment: Hey Jason. We finally decided to switch from .asf to flash. Those .flv videos won't be on YouTube but on our own server. Is there a way to use theese functions (getCurrentTime, seekTo....) on our embeded player?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://jasonlau.biz/home/jlembed-for-jquery/jlembed-youtube-api), the following functions exist that might help:

- jlembed_seekTo(playerId, seconds, allowSeekAhead)
- jlembed_getCurrentTime(playerId)

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, but theese functions are only for YouTube player. Looks like that jlembed put most of it's time in developing functions for youtube.